# Why would the CLUSTERED UNIQUE CONSTRAINT impact the number of times the CURSOR iterates(doubles) when updating a column of the unique constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Steps to reproduce

Please note that this is a much much watered-down version of the business implementation. The use of a cursor is required for updating rows individually while skipping rows with constraints and business rule violations while logging what worked and didn't amongst many other reasons.

1. Create the table and insert the data

```
USE [database];
GO
-- Drop table
IF(EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
          AND TABLE_NAME = 'Employee'
))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE dbo.Employee;
END;
-- Create table
IF(NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
          AND TABLE_NAME = 'Employee'
))
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE dbo.[Employee]
        (EmpId     INT, 
         Org       VARCHAR(100), 
         Job       VARCHAR(100), 
         Gender    CHAR NOT NULL, 
         StartDate DATE NOT NULL, 
         EndDate   DATE NULL, 
         CONSTRAINT PK_EmpId PRIMARY KEY(EmpId), 

         -- WORKS as expected iterating through twice updating two records
         CONSTRAINT UQ_Employee_EmpId_Job_EndDate UNIQUE (EmpId, Job, EndDate),

         -- DOES NOT WORK! - Iterates through the table x2 where the fetch next does not get the next row. Same row is fetched again and therefore it's looped twice.
         -- CONSTRAINT UQ_Employee_EmpId_Job_EndDate UNIQUE CLUSTERED (EmpId, Job, EndDate),

        );
END;
-- Insert data
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100200', 'ITM', 'SD', 'M', DATEADD(DAY, 2, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100201', 'ITM', 'SE', 'F', DATEADD(DAY, 3, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100202', 'ITM', 'BA', 'F', DATEADD(DAY, 5, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100203', 'ITM', 'PM', 'M', DATEADD(DAY, 3, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100204', 'ITM', 'UI', 'F', DATEADD(DAY, 4, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100205', 'ITM', 'UX', 'F', DATEADD(DAY, 3, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100206', 'ITM', 'SL', 'M', DATEADD(DAY, 3, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100207', 'ITM', 'SL', 'M', DATEADD(DAY, 3, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee values('100208', 'ITM', 'SE', 'F', DATEADD(DAY, 2, '1/1/2019'), NULL);
```

2. Crete the procedure

```
USE [database];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

-- ==================================================================
-- Author:                UR
-- Create date:           01/10/2019
-- Description:           End date any 'active' employee in org ITM with a job type of SE to Today
-- ==================================================================
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Set_EndEmp
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @emp_id INT;
        DECLARE @loop_count INT;
        DECLARE @job VARCHAR(100);
        DECLARE @org VARCHAR(100);
        DECLARE @gender CHAR;
        DECLARE @start_date DATE;
        DECLARE @end_dat DATE;
        SET @org = 'ITM';
        SET @job = 'SE';
        SET @loop_count = 0;
        -- Open cursor for the JSON payload 
        DECLARE refcursor CURSOR LOCAL
        -- Convert the JSON to a relational table
        FOR SELECT EmpId, 
                   Job
            FROM dbo.[Employee]
            WHERE Org = @org
                  AND Job = @job;

        -- Open the cursor
        OPEN refcursor;
        -- Fetch the first/next records into the varaibles
        FETCH NEXT FROM refcursor INTO @emp_id, @job;

        -- Chek if the fetch statement is successful = 0
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                -- End date any 'active' employee in org ITM with a job type of SE to Today
                UPDATE dbo.[Employee]
                  SET 
                      EndDate = GETDATE()
                WHERE EmpId = @emp_id
                      AND Job = @job
                      AND EndDate IS NULL;

                -- Fetch the next record
                PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('Before fetch: [%d]', @emp_id);

                -- Fetch next row
                FETCH NEXT FROM refcursor INTO @emp_id, @job;

                PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('After fetch:  [%d]', @emp_id);

                -- Increment the count
                SET @loop_count = @loop_count + 1;
                PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('Count:       [%d]', @loop_count);
                PRINT '-------';
            END;
        CLOSE refcursor;
        DEALLOCATE refcursor;
    END;
    GO
```

3. Execute the procedure

```
EXECUTE dbo.Set_EndEmp;
```

4. Results when the CONSTRAINT is as below - - **Correct** results, works as expected by updating 2 rows

CONSTRAINT UQ_Employee_EmpId_Job_EndDate UNIQUE (EmpId, Job, EndDate),

```
Before fetch: [100201]
After fetch:  [100208] <-- The correct next row is fetched
Count:        [1]
-------

(1 row affected)
Before fetch: [100208]
After fetch:  [100208]
Count:        [2]
```

5. Results when the CONSTRAINT is as below - **Incorrect** results, The same row is updated twice since the cursor loops four times.

CONSTRAINT UQ_Employee_EmpId_Job_EndDate UNIQUE **CLUSTERED** (EmpId, Job, EndDate),

```
Before fetch: [100201]
After fetch:  [100201] <--- The same row is fetched again!
Count:        [1]
-------

(0 rows affected)
Before fetch: [100201]
After fetch:  [100208]
Count:        [2]
-------

(1 row affected)
Before fetch: [100208]
After fetch:  [100208] <--- The same row is fetched again!
Count:        [3]
-------

(0 rows affected)
Before fetch: [100208]
After fetch:  [100208]
Count:        [4]
```

As shown, after the FETCH the same row is retrieved **again** when it's a UNIQUE CLUSTERED CONSTRAINT. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm kind of not surprised that it happens, although I cannot immediately find the place in the documentation that explains why. To fix it, don't engage in funny business of separately updating the table you are enumerating with a cursor and use the cursor for that instead: `DECLARE refcursor CURSOR local keyset forward_only FOR SELECT EmpId, Job FROM dbo.[Employee] WHERE Org = @org AND Job = @job for update of EndDate;`, `UPDATE dbo.[Employee] SET EndDate = isnull(EndDate, GETDATE()) WHERE current of refcursor;`. At which point you might realise you don't need a cursor in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the documentation @GSerg. I have tried a forward-only cursor with the UPDATE of Enddate when I was isolating the issue and didn't have any luck and unfortunately, I still don't. Perhaps a reindexing occures when updating a clustered constraint while iterating through the same table? I can't find any literature to support the argument. However, I can safely update a variety of primary keys whilst iterating without any issues.

Comment: I tried the code I suggested (`WHERE current of refcursor`), and it showed same behaviour with and without clustered index.

Comment: You are correct. My apologies! I missed `keyset`. This works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the official documentation of [`declare cursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
Specifically, note the `INSENSITIVE` optional keyword:

> INSENSITIVE
>   Defines a cursor that makes a temporary copy of the data to be used by the cursor. All requests to the cursor are answered from this temporary table in **tempdb**; therefore, modifications made to base tables are not reflected in the data returned by fetches made to this cursor, and this cursor does not allow modifications. **When ISO syntax is used, if INSENSITIVE is omitted, committed deletes and updates made to the underlying tables (by any user) are reflected in subsequent fetches.**

Though this is only relevant when you're using *ISO Syntax*, there is a *Transact-SQL Extended Syntax* equivalent for it - which is `STATIC`:

> STATIC
>   Specifies that the cursor always displays the result set as it was when the cursor was first opened, and makes a temporary copy of the data to be used by the cursor. All requests to the cursor are answered from this temporary table in tempdb. Therefore inserts, updates, and deletes made to base tables are not reflected in the data returned by fetches made to this cursor [...]

If you change your `DECLARE refcursor CURSOR LOCAL` to `DECLARE refcursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC` that should fix the problem.

The fact that your cursor is not static means that for every `fetch next` operation there's a read to of the current data - and since you are updating the clustered index, you are effecting the order on which the rows are saved internally on the disk.

Since your cursor doesn't have an `order by` clause, this means that every `fetch next` might yield an unexpected row - since without `order by` the resultset is unsorted - more accurately - it's order is arbitrary. Apparently, changing the clustered index cause SQL Server to change the order of the resultset - and this is why you're not getting the row you're expecting to get.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the explanation. DECLARE refcursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC works!

Comment: Glad to help :-)